# Where does animation render save when output folder location doesn't exist

Tags: rendering, animation, saving

I have a question about location where finished rendered animation saves..

I have started rendering on one computer where I have specified the path to save folder. BUT I have now continued the rendering on a new computer where i have stopped on previous computer.

However, I forgot to change the save location. So the path in blend file does not exist on new computer. This path is non-exsistant.

Where did the rendering go now? (If it even did, or it just goes to nothing?) I tried C:/Windows/Temp, but no success there. (I'm on Win10 btw)

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a screen shot of your render settings, the *output* section is especially important.

Comment: It saved normally on the previous computer on the specified folder location. Problem is that I just opened the blend file on a new computer without changing the location. So this location folder location doesn't exist on this new computer. I'm just wondering where does the render go then?

Comment: On my Windows setup the non-existent output folder was created automatically when rendering an animation.

Comment: Where was the location of that folder?

Comment: I just searched the whole computer for a file named after the last frame number. And no results came up. Does that mean that the rendering just went into nothing?

Comment: I changed the output folder from "/tmp\" to "/tmpast\" and I ended up with C:\tmpast with the results. I also tried "/tmpast" and got no errors but could not find any rendered frames.

Comment: I found the render! It was in Recover (E:) drive. Note, I'm using Win10. Hope this help anyone in the future

Answer (score 0):

Still, when Blender can't find the directory you selected for the output it creates a new one starting from the local disk. Just copy the directory you erroneously wrote for the output and search for it in the folders.

I had for example one directory called `home/blender/project/render`, blender created a `home` directory in local disk, next `program files` and `users`